# Truffle Compile Error (Invalid input source specified, Compilation Failed)

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle-compile

When I run truffle compile, it throws the following error:
`Invalid input source specified.`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is typically caused by a bad import statement. Check that something isn't being included incorrectly. A good example would be something like:

```
import 'MyContract.sol';
```

as opposed to

```
import './MyContract.sol';
```